# Is it safe to use static getters with Realm?

Tags: java, android, static, realm

This question is the sequel of my previous one : [Is it safe to use ActiveRecord pattern with Realm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169887/is-it-safe-to-use-activerecord-pattern-with-realm)

Is it safe to use convenient static getters like this one ?

```
public static List<ItemRealm> getListByBar(String bar){
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<ItemRealm> rtn = realm.where(ItemRealm.class).equalTo("foo", bar).findAll();
    //realm.close();
    return rtn;
}
```

By the comments on my previous post, it seems I should close the realm, but if I do my item are no longer usable.

For this is a request I make very often in my code, I want to have a delegated method.

What is the recommanded way to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

It's only safe if your Realm lifecycle is managed outside of this method.

```
public static List<ItemRealm> getListByBar(Realm realm, String bar) {
    //Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    return realm.where(ItemRealm.class).equalTo("foo", bar).findAll();
    //realm.close();
}
```

Although I wonder how you intend to keep it synchronized if you expose it as a `List<>` and therefore cannot add a `RealmChangeListener`.

Comment: For this use, I dont really need RealmChangeListeners. But isn't it a problem for every `findAll()` uses ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if the results get updated, you can't seem to get notified about it this way.

Comment: I meant this is a problem with `findAll()` which returns a List, not a problem with the delegated static method, isn't it ?

Comment: if the results get updated, you can't seem to get notified about it this way. Please check [my other answer about getting notified by changes to the results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43192015/realm-working-with-clean-architecture-and-rxjava2/43202425#43202425)